# War Themed Cryptic Clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

Today is Memorial Day in the United States. In honor of those who gave their lives in war, here are some cryptic clues, the answers of which will be war related. They may be about famous battles, generals, wars, or tactics.

> In tunnels on hold (6)
>
> Race a torn ham confusedly (8)
>
> Jumps morning plants (8)
>
> Sport losing half its hole for bay (4)
>
> Liquid at the toilet station (8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In tunnels on hold (6)

> Nelson - tunNELS ON, a [hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_hold) in wrestling ([the admiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horatio_Nelson,_1st_Viscount_Nelson))

Race a torn ham confusedly (8)

> Marathon - anagram of A TORN HAM, a race ([the battlefield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon#History))

Jumps morning plants (8)

> Ambushes - A.M. + BUSHES, to jump an unsuspecting party ([a tactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambush))

Sport losing half its hole for bay (4)

> Gulf - GOLF without part of it's hole 'O', a bay ([the war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War))

Liquid at the toilet station (8)

> Waterloo - WATER + LOO, a main railway [station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Waterloo_station) in London, U.K. ([the battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Waterloo))

Comment: I accepted this answer because it contained all five solutions and linked them to the theme.

Answer (score 4):

In tunnels on hold (6)

> **Nelson** (In tun**nels on**, definition: hold)

Race a torn ham confusedly (8)

> **Marathon** (Definition: Race, "a torn ham" anagrammed = marathon)

Jumps morning plants (8)

> **Ambushes** (from Jonathan Allan's answer, Definition: Jumps, morning=AM + plants=BUSHES)

Sport losing half its hole for bay (4)

> **Gulf** (Golf losing half its hole = Gulf, definition: bay)

Liquid at the toilet station (8)

> **Waterloo** (Liquid=water at the toilet=loo, definition: station)